# How Install scikit-learn package on pypy?

Tags: pip, pypy

```
create virtualenv -p pypy3 pypy3.
```

I had upgraded Pip so that I can install other packages:

```
pypy3 -m ensurepip
pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

PyPy 7.3.5 with GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux,
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

But it waits so long after run command:

```
pypy3 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use conda-forge, they supply binary packages for many common libraries like scikit-learn:

```
$ conda create -c conda-forge -n pypy3.7 pypy
$ conda activate pypy3.7
(pypy3.7)$ conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```